# How can I cause the state_machine block to use the default accessor instead of my custom accessor?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine, accessor

I'm implementing [pluginaweek's state_machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). I narrowed the code down to just this so I can understand the problem more easily. Let's assume I only have one status for now:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :status, :initial => :active_offer do
  end

  def status
    'Active Offer'
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting when creating new Event objects either via seeding or via the browser is `{:status=>["is invalid"]}`.

The plan is to include a condition for all the different statuses and return a custom string to the view. The entire project's views currently use the `.status` syntax so I'm trying to smoothly install this. I started this solution based on reading the api docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Overwriting+default+accessors

This is my main goal:

```
def status
  if read_attribute(:status) == 'active_offer' && self.start_date > Time.now
    'Active Offer'
  elsif read_attribute(:status) == 'active_offer' && self.start_date < Time.now
    'Expired'
  else read_attribute(:status) == 'cancelled'
    'Cancelled'
  end
end
```

What can I do to make the state_machine block use the normal accessor so it gets the database value?

**THE SILVER BULLET SOLUTION:**

My main problem was the accessor override `status`. When state_machine code was running, it was reading the current status through my accessor override and therefore getting a custom string returned, which was an invalid status. I had to make state_machine use :state. I didn't do this originally because I already had a :state attr for provinces and such, so I migrated that to :address_state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need to change the definition's name:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :status, :initial => :active_offer do
  end

  def active_offer
    'Active Offer'
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

If I understand you correctly, which I'm not certain I do, this will work:

```
state_machine :status, initial: :active_offer do
  event :expire do
    transition all => :expired
  end
  event :cancel do
    transition all => :cancelled
  end
end
```

Then you can do your `if...` statements, etc., in the controller or something, and transition them with something like `@event.expire` or `if @event.expired`. If you want it automated you'll need something like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include enough info the first time to help people understand what my main goal was. Please review my edits if you can, maybe that will alter your solution so I can keep it as 'status'. Thanks.

Comment: So do you want it to happen automatically or are you firing these methods with buttons or something similar?

Comment: No buttons firing. For right now, say I've got an index of events. One of the columns in the table of events on the index view is status. So I'd like to keep that code the same, and just edit what it gets from the Model.

Comment: thanks for the efforts so far. To get you on the same page as me (!), let's say in my show view, I want something like `@event.status` to return "Active Offer" or whatever string based on the conditions inside the accessor.

Comment: I think the string would be something like "active_offer" based on the symbol. I need something like "Active Offer", and other custom strings for all the other states/statuses. Thanks again for continuing.

Comment: Ah! Too easy. You want `@event.status.titlecase`. Boom.